# Match a select box value when another select box value is chosen/

Tags: jquery

We're creating a select box of countries for billing and delivery.

When one select box is chosen for billing we want it to update the delivery select box..

Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You need something like -

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<hr>
<select id="second">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>


$("#first").change(function() {
    $("#second").val($(this).val())
});
```

That will set the value of the second select to the value of the first, if you want to set the value of the second select to something depending on the value of the first you'd have to add an if statement.

```
$("#first").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "something") {
       $("#second").val("something else");
    }
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uxpHv/

Comment: @Andy, it's a pleasure. I'd really appreciate it if you could upvote/accept the answer if it has helped. Thanks :)